# delete! function for R5RS

Tags: linked-list, scheme, filtering, mutable, r5rs

I'm trying to write a `delete!` function that mutates a list and removes from it a specified value. This is the code I have so far.

```
(define (extend! l . xs)
  (if (null? (cdr l))
      (set-cdr! l xs)
      (apply extend! (cdr l) xs)))

(define (delete! lis y)
  (define returnLis '())
  (for-each (lambda(x) (if(not(eq? x y))
                          (extend! returnLis x))) lis)
  returnLis)
```

The problem I am having is that I am trying to add to an empty list which can't be done in Scheme.

Desired outcome:

> (delete! '(1 2 3 4 5) 3) 
>   => (1 2 4 5)

Comment: And the problem you're having is...? Post an example demonstrating the problem, and the result you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Your `extend` function use actually would make a copy of each element in a fresh pair, but since the initial value is `'()` it cannot be `set-cdr!`. The whole point of mutating something is that old variables will continue point to the changed data and making a copy won't do that.

You need to see the pairs. You want to remove 3

```
[1,-]->[2,-]->[3,-]->[4,-]->[5,-]->()
```

So When you have found 3, you need to change the `cdr` of the pair that holds 2 and pint it the pair that holds 3s `cdr` like this:

```
[1,-]->[2,-]->[4,-]->[5,-]->()
```

Something like this then:

```
(define (delete lst e)
  (if (and (not (null? lst)) (not (null? (cdr lst))))
      (if (equal? (cadr lst) e)
          (set-cdr! lst (cddr lst))
          (delete (cdr lst) e))
      'undefined))

(define test (list 1 2 3 4 5)) 
(delete lst 3)
lst ; ==> (1 2 4 5)
```

Notice I'm using `list` since a quoted literal cannot be used here since you are not allowed to change constant data like `'(1 2 3 4 5)`. The result will be undefined or it will signal an error.

It won't work if the element in question is the first. It's because the variable points to the first pair and this only changes the pointers in pairs, not bindings. One could just switch the two first and delete the second, but in the event you have a one element list you are still stuck. Scheme implementations of mutable queues usually have a head consisting of a dummy element not considered part of the list to delete the first element.

Comment: building a copy through mutation (while removing some elements) is a perfectly valid technique.

Comment: @WillNess Yes, but its not the same as OPs intention that it "mutates a list and removes from it a specified value" since that warrants actually mutating the argument pairs. Also only internal mutation not exposed wouldn't warrant the exclamation mark.

Comment: ah, yes, missed that entirely. :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a *head-sentinel technique*:

```
(define (delete! lis y)
  (define returnLis (list 1))
  (for-each (lambda(x) (if(not(eq? x y))
                          (extend! returnLis x))) lis)
  (cdr returnLis))
```

Well, not *all*... because as it is, this is a quadratic algorithm. It re-searches the `returnLis` from top anew while adding each new element with `extend!`. Better just maintain the *last cdr cell* and update *it*:

```
(define (delete! lis y)
  (define returnLis (list 1))
  (define last-cell returnLis)
  (for-each (lambda(x) (cond ((not(eq? x y))
                          ; (extend! last-cell x)
                          (set-cdr! last-cell (list x))
                          (set! last-cell (cdr last-cell)))))
            lis)
  (cdr returnLis))
```

But, as @Sylwester [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797803/delete-function-for-r5rs/42807399#comment72727873_42799310), with this approach you shouldn't use an exclamation mark in the name, as this will return a *freshly built* list instead of mutating the argument's structure.